# Dictionary Application Failing To Return Results

Tags: c#, tokenize

I am creating a simple dictionary using c#. Here is the code that matters:

```
enOutput.Text = "Ní Rézelnasin / No Results";
            string dictText = DictResource.knendict.ToString();

            string[] lines = dictText.Split('\n');
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] entries = line.Split('=');

                if (knInput.Text == entries[1])
                {

                    enOutput.Text = entries[0];
                }
            }
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. The dictionary format is structured like this:

```
english word=knashta equivalent
```

Like,

```
hello=ahoj
the=sé
dictionary=diktsíonarísinsta
```

But, if I enter `ahoj`, I get no results back.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit, after trying:

```
var text = DictResource.knendict.ToString();
var dict = text.Split(new[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(part => part.Split('='))
           .ToDictionary(split => split[1], split => split[0]);
enOutput.Text = dict[knInput.Text];
```

I get this error message:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
   at ShellApp.Dictionary.getEnglish_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: How are you adding the pairs to the dictionary? Do you perhaps have the key/value round the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

Seems silly to be building a dictionary-type app and not using a `Dictionary<key, value>` type structure...

```
var text = DictResource.knendict.ToString();
var dict = text.Split(new[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(part => part.Split('='))
           .ToDictionary(split => split[1], split => split[0]);
```

This code would build up a dictionary of `knashta equivalent -> english translation` so you would use it like

```
Console.WriteLine(dict["ahoj"]); // hello
```

Comment: This seems easier / better. I'll try it.

Comment: @Igor Please remember this is not a help desk site. You should not change your question to something regarding a different issue and expect someone to keep correcting their answer along with your attempts to finish your code.

Comment: @Igor according to the exception it appears you have multiple translations in your list. My answer assumes you have a unique 1-to-1 mapping.